# boost::multi_index_container: How to use composite_key (x,y) to support rectangular search?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container
< Record,
  indexed_by 
  < ordered_non_unique 
    < tag<ByP>,
      composite_key < Record,
                      const_mem_fun<Record, double, &Record::hit_x>,
                      const_mem_fun<Record, double, &Record::hit_y>
    >
  >,   // ...
>
```

As you can see, there is index by Point(x,y) (`ByP`).
Now I'm using the next function:

```
size_t  adjacencyRectPoints (std::list<Record> &range, const Point  &min, const Point &max)
{
  MultiIndexMoves::index<ByP>::type  &index = store_.get<ByP> ();     
  /* Range searching, i.e.the lookup of all elements in a given interval */
  auto itFirstLower = index.lower_bound (boost::tuple<double, double> (min));
  auto itFirstUpper = index.upper_bound (boost::tuple<double, double> (max));

  size_t count = 0U;
  for ( auto it = itFirstLower; it != itFirstUpper; ++it )
  {
    if ( (min.x <= it->hit.x && min.y <= it->hit.y)
      && (max.x >= it->hit.x && max.y >= it->hit.y) )
    {
      range.push_back (*it);
      ++count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

This function returns all points from rectangle: (min.x < x < max.x && min.y < y < max.y). It is working.

But, how you can see, the container returns much more points, that I expected, and I have to filter them one more time.
I think, that acting is wrong.

---

I thought, that I had to define the comparator by myself to get only right points. But that way of comparing is not fit for boost::multi_index_container:

```
struct Compare
{
  bool  operator() (const Point &p, const Point &q) const
  { return  (p.x < q.x) && (p.y < q.y); }
};
```

(first comment @RichardHodges)

Comment: that comparator is wrong. it's not reversible. you'll get keys that are neither less than or greater than other keys when the x's are equal and the y's are different.

Comment: "t is very important to get the AND-operator between the keys compare_result" - In that case I somehow fail to see how this is a multi-index.

Comment: @VolkerK, Container searches independently by x and y, then takes it intersection - it means that each key comparator returned true.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I'm trying to organize the region searching in that container, I have chosen the incorrect way?

Comment: @KirillGolikov what (in words) defines a discrete region?

Comment: @RichardHodges, Return all of points belongs to Rectangle: (x1 <= x <= x2 && y1 <= y <= y2). I'm using `auto itFirstLower = index.lower_bound (min); auto  itFirstUpper = index.upper_bound (max); ...` But there is no checking by ordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the comparator seems wrong to me (it doesn't look like it does define a total weak ordering as required).

Secondly, the key type on a composite key is logically a tuple of the constituent parts. The default comparison implementation is provided by boost (as a a lexicographical memberwise comparison¹).

This is much more likely to be what you want. If you **must** override it some way, use: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#composite_key_compare

---

¹ `<boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>` and c++11's std::tuple also defines the same operators

Comment: I have read the docs, but do not understand, how to organize the region searching in the container. The default order is unfit for it, but if my comparator is wrong, I do not understand where a correct place to integrate this code.

Comment: I suspect your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778119/boost-multi-index-composite-key-for-multiple-column-indexes

Comment: @KirillGolikov I'm happy to help out if you can update your question with an example what you mean by "region searching" (are you referring to `equal_range` on a partial key? I have several [answers showing samples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+composite_key).). Make sure you describe _what_ you want to achieve more than _how_ you think you need to do it.

Comment: Okay. This clearly indicates that the library author got the right hunch in his comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634751/boostmulti-index-container-how-to-use-composite-key-x-y-to-support-rectangu/36635239#comment60882304_36635239. Look at boost rtree perhaps